# Get Express Route Regex From Path

Tags: regex, express

I'm trying to create a function that, given a path, will return the Express route regex that is used for that path. If I have:

```
app.get('/a/b/c/:slug(a-z)', (req, res) => {
  res.send('ok')
});
```

I want to be able to have a function:

```
function getRoute(path) {
   // ...
}

getRoute('/a/b/c/whatever') // => '/a/b/c/:slug(a-z0-9*)'
```

In a request, I can access an express Route object at `req.route`. It looks like this:

```
{  
   "path":"/a/b/c/:slug(a-z0-9*)",
   "stack":[ ... ],
   "methods":{  
      "get":true
   }
}
```

But I'm looking for a way to do this given no request context, such that it can be called anywhere. I have `app` context available. Is there some sort of routing tool inside the Express app that I can tap into?

@jfriend00, here's what I'm trying to do.

I've got a route, let's say:

```
app.get('/my-blog/:slug', (req, res) => {
  ...
});
```

And the site supports multiple languages. So let's say we have an article called "Hello World". In this case, the slug is `hello-world` and so the route is:

`/my-blog/hello-world`

However, I need a french version too. So the route is now:

```
app.get('/my-blog/:slug|/mon-blog/:slug', (req, res) => {
  ...
});
```

Cool, so that works no problem. Now, the site is server generated, and I'm using [i18n2](https://github.com/jeresig/i18n-node-2) to translate everything. I also need to translate the links on the site. However, when I come across the URL: `/my-blog/hello-world` on a French page, I need to translate it to `/mon-blog/bonjour-le-monde`. Assume a blog post has a french and english slug and can be retrieved by either, so all these URLs would *work*:

- `/mon-blog/bonjour-le-monde`
- `/my-blog/bonjour-le-monde` (this would never be used)
- `/mon-blog/hello-world` (this would never be used)
- `/my-blog/hello-world`

I also need to redirect a user who arrives at `/my-blog/hello-world` to `/mon-blog/bonjour-le-monde` if their browser language is set to French.

The only solutions that I can think of are things like generating a mapping of all URLs to their french counterparts, which is a bit gross. I'd really rather use something that has some first class support if possible. Appreciate your input.

Comment: Not that I'm aware of.  Matching routes in Express happens in the context of an incoming request object.  What problem are you really trying to solve here that leads you to ask for this?

Comment: Express does this to get a request path to a route, so it must be done somewhere, doesn't it? It's part of a solution to localize URLs even when those URLs have a parameter that is also able to be localized.

Comment: Yeah, but when Express does it, it's done in the context of an incoming request object which you said you don't want to have.  You'd have to use the internals of Express data structures to write your own code to find this.  Why are you trying to do this?  I can't help but think there might be a more supported way to attack whatever it is you're trying to do.

Comment: @jfriend00 I've updated my question with some more details about the problem.

Comment: So, the original problem is how to translate the link `/my-blog/hello-world` to `/mon-blog/bonjour-le-monde` when the user's browser is french (and do that for all the links in a page)?

Comment: Correct - so redirect the user if they arrive at a URL of the wrong language, and then translate all the links in a page. Translating the links in the page is where I don't have a request context.

Comment: Can you assume that the translation is always one-way, from English to some other language?  So, the pages will be pre-built with the English links and the problem is always to translate them to some other language?  This would make the lookup task easier and faster if one can make that assumption.

Comment: Well in the case of the redirect, if an English user reaches a french localized URL, it will have to be reversed, from French to English. But for URLs in a page, they will always be English and translated to French or some other language.

Comment: OK, I have an interesting idea for how to do it without any internal Express hacking.  Will take a little time to work out some details.  Will post when I get the time to work it out and write it up.  Might be later in the day.

Comment: @jfriend00 go for it! Looking forward to seeing what you come up with.

Comment: I ran into a snag.  When translating a page to French that has a link to `/my-blog/hello-world`, the proposal I'm working on can find that it matches the route `/my-blog/:slug` and that the french version of that route is `/mon-blog/:slug`, but how do you propose translating `hello-world` to French so that you can insert `/mon-blog/bonjour-le-monde` into the page?  That info isn't contained anywhere in your routing.  So, I feel like I can get you the routing definition for the other language, but not a fully translated URL.

Comment: And, since the slug itself can be anything and isn't in your route definitions, this seems like a generic translation problem.  If I just get you the route definition in the other language, are you going to handle the rest?

Comment: @jfriend00 I can handle the slug translations, as each blog post has both an english and a french slug that I can reference it by.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your edit appropriately, the original problem is how to translate the link `/my-blog/hello-world` to `/mon-blog/bonjour-le-monde` when the user's browser is french (and do that for all the other links in a page)?

Here's an idea:

Instead, of using `app.get()`, use some wrapper function that both registers the desired routes with Express and creates an ability to look up routes for matching purposes.  Then, rather than using undocumented internals from Express, you just capture the data into your own data structures where you can use it as you like.  Here's a module that could be used for that purpose:

```
// this is the library that Express uses for converting express 
//   route definitions to regular expressions
const pathToRegexp = require('path-to-regexp');

// this is an array of arrays or route regular expressions
// the top level array will be in route definition order
// the sub arrays contain an object for each language and must be in a consistent language order
//   with English first and then other languages to follow in a consistent order
// For example the sub-array could be routes for English, French, German, Italian in that order
// The object for each language has properties:
//    route - original express route string
//    keys - keys returned by pathToRegexp
//    re - regular expression for this route
//    verb - http verb "get", "post", etc... for this route
const allRoutes = [];

// create one of these for each router you are defining matchable routes on
// Then, instead of app.get(...) to define your routes, do it like this:
// const appW = new RouterWrapper(app);
// appW.get(['/my-blog/hello-world', '/mon-blog/bonjour-le-monde'], (req, res) => { ... });
// This wrapper object will both register the route in Express and build a lookup mechanism for mapping routes
class RouterWrapper() {
    constructor(router) {
        this.router = router;
    }
    // common function used by all the verbs
    _register(routes, verb, ...fn) {
        // register route with express
        // join all of them together in a regex
        let joinedRoute = routes.join("|");
        this.router[verb](joinedRoute, ...fn);

        // save this set of routes in our master list
        allRoutes.push(routes.map(route => {
            let obj = {keys: [], route, verb};
            obj.re = pathToRegexp(route, obj.keys);
            return obj;
        }));
    }

    // pass in an English Route
    // returns first route that matches
    static getRouteData(englishRoute, languageIndex, verb = "get") {
        for (let data of allRoutes) {
            // english route is always in position 0 in the array
            if (data[0].verb === verb && data[0].re.test(englishRoute)) {
                return data[languageIndex];
            }
        }
        // not found
        return null;        
    }
}

// add actual verb methods
["get", "post", "put"].forEach(verb => {
    // all verb methods call common function
    RouterWrapper.protototype[verb] = function(path, ...fn) {
        return this._register(path, verb, ...fn;)
    };
});

module.exports = RouterWrapper;
```

The idea is that you would use it like this:

```
// usage
let RouterWrapper = require('router-wrapper');

let appWrapper = new RouterWrapper(app);

// you define these indexes based on how you order your URLs
const englishIndex = 0;
const frenchIndex = 1;

// define routes
appWrapper.get(['/my-blog/:slug','/mon-blog/:slug'], (req, res) => {
    ...
});
```

Then, to lookup a particular English path:

```
let routeData = RouterWrapper.getRouteData('/my-blog//hello-world', frenchIndex);
console.log(routeData.route);    // '/mon-blog/:slug`
```

Per your comments, translating the slug would be left to you since that information is not in the route definitions.

---

Caveats:

1. This code is not tested and may contain some mistakes.  I'm hopefully giving you a directional idea for how to do this without using Express internals.
2. This assumes a world where you're just trying to find the first route that matches.
3. This assumes there is no dynamic routing in your app that you need this to work for (e.g. no programmatic examination of URLs).
4. Do not define your middleware through the wrapper.  Use regular `app.use()` for those.

Comment: With a few changes to the `getRouteData` function, I was able to get localization working both ways. That is, I can provide it a french path, and ask for english, and it will give back the English URL. All I did was loop over the regexes for that route and check each one, then return the requested language from that route if any of them match. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @JamieCounsell - I can see how that would work when you're deciding whether to redirect or not and don't know the starting language.  For translation in the page, I think you only want to look at the English routes (for performance reasons), particularly if you have lots of languages.  Anyway, glad to you have an idea you could make work for you.

Answer (score 2):

I should preface this by saying that express 4 [hides the router](https://github.com/expressjs/express/wiki/Migrating-from-3.x-to-4.x#approuter).

This solution relies on private internals of express. Exercise caution.

The express router internally maintains an array of *layers*. When handling a request it looks at these layers one by one and tests whether they match the request path.

You could use an approach similar to the following to mimic the internal behavior of express.

```
    function getRoutePath(path) {
            var stack = app._router.stack;
            for (var i = 0; i < stack.length; i++) {
                    if (stack[i].route && stack[i].match(path)) {
                            return stack[i].route.path;
                    }
            }
    }
```

This takes a path and returns the pattern for the first route that matched.

```
    app.get('/foo/:bar', (req, res) => {
            res.send('ok')
    });

    getRoutePath('/foo/gotcha'); // -> "/foo/:bar"
```

Comment: How would you handle multiple routers defined as part of the app?  middleware that also matches the route? Programmatic decisions that determine actual routing?  handlers for different http verbs like `app.post()` and `app.get()` that match the same route, but might have a different regex?

Comment: That's the trouble with using private internals to reimplement internal logic. 

Comment: Oops, I took too long to edit. I wanted to say: Those are all good points. This is the trouble with using private internals to reimplement internal logic. It is an imperfect solution, but it may be sufficient for use in a simple app.

Comment: Yeah, I just wanted the OP to understand the limitations.